# How to dynamically create div class="row" using Django and Booststarp

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to render some cards dynamically in my webpage. I want to render four cards in the first row and wants to render four more cards in the next row. How can I render div dynamically using django?

Here is the **view.py**

```py
def User_View_Packages(request):
    package = Package.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'user_view_packages.html',{'package':package})
```

And **index.html**

```
<div class="row">
    {% for p in package %}
    <div class="col-md">
        
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;margin-left:5%">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="dp.39069 (1).jpeg" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{ p.package_name }}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">STARTS FROM BDT. {{ p.package_cost }} PER PERSON</p>
                <p class="card-text">Location: INDIA</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View More</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the code below

```
<div class="row">

{% for p in package %}

    <div class="col-md-3"><!-- HERE -->
        <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm"><!-- HERE -->
            <img class="card-img-top" src="dp.39069 (1).jpeg" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{ p.package_name }}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">STARTS FROM BDT. {{ p.package_cost }} PER PERSON</p>
                <p class="card-text">Location: INDIA</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View More</a>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.card -->
    </div><!-- /.col-md-3 -->
   
   {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:4 %}</div><div class="row">{% endif %}  {# HERE #}

{% endfor %}

</div><!-- /.row -->
```

refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#divisibleby